# Data transparency in a meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis

In a meta-analysis project, we extracted data from published papers. Now, we are going to submit it in a journal. But, in the Declarations section, the journal requires a statement for "Availability of data and material (data transparency)". What will be the availability of data for a meta-analysis manuscript?

Also, another requirement in the Declarations section is Code availability (software application or custom code). We used Stata version 14.1. But we wrote our own codes. What will be the code availability in our case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are presenting the data in a forest plot then everything you used is visible in that plot since it is conventional to include the effect size and confidence interval for each study in that plot. So I would just state that all the data is included in the paper. You will also presumably have a list of the papers which you extracted the data from so readers can check it really is the data from the primary studies.

If your journal has supplementary material for papers then put the do files there. If they do not then either (a) do not include them and wait to be asked (b) provide a link to your GitHub repository or wherever they can find the code.